# How to get WorkerID in external Qualification Test in Mechanical Turk

Tags: mechanicalturk

I created a external test (which tests whether a user can use Google chrome developer console or not). After the test, the test automatically needs to assign the qualification to the worker. Now my question is how do I get the workerID? I have already seen externalHIT. Lemme know how do I use that in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of unclear, but here are some ideas.

Are you talking about a QualificationTest? If so, you can configure it to grant the qualification automatically using the `AutoGranted` parameter in the [`CreateQualificationType`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_CreateQualificationTypeOperation.html) operation.

If not granted automatically, you can use the [`GetQualificationRequests`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_GetQualificationRequestsOperation.html) operation, which includes the WorkerId (called `SubjectId` in the API response).